# Show the following is true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ be sets. Show the following is true

> 1. For any sets $X,Y$: $P(X)\cup P(Y)\subseteq P(X\cup Y)$.

Answer:

$A \in P(X) \cup P(Y)$.
Then $A\in P(X)$ or $A\in P(Y)$.
It follows that $A\subseteq X$ or $A\subseteq Y$.
So $A \subseteq X \cup Y$. Therefore, $P(X) \cup P(Y)\subseteq P(X\cup Y)$.

> 2. $P(A \cap B) \subseteq P(A \cup B)$

Someone help me with the correct answer please.

Comment: Show some work, i.e., tell us how you have tried to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X\in P(A\cap B)$. Then $X\subseteq A$ and $X\subseteq B$. Then $X\subseteq A\cup B$. So $X\in P(A\cup B)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is because if $X\subseteq Y$, then $\;\mathcal P(X)\subseteq \mathcal P(Y)$ (any subset of X is *ipso facto*  a subset of $Y$).